# Alternative ways to rename a flat file in Java

Tags: java, file, rename

So im writing a program that reads a txt file that the user provides the name of from a specific folder

I want to rename the .txt after the user has opened it. However, nothing happens

```
            temp = userInput;

            currentFileDir = "D:\\Document\\" + username + "\\" + temp1 ;
            File directory = new File(currentFileDir + ".txt");
                Scanner readingFile = new Scanner(directory);

                while (readingFile.hasNextLine())
                {
                   txtdata = txtdata + readingFile.nextLine() + "  ";
                }


            File newName = new File(currentFileDir + "--OPENED.txt");

            directory.renameTo(newName);

            System.out.println(txtdata);

            }
```

Is there something wrong with the code I provided?

I've tried using it in a standalone program and it works fine, so I think that the rest of the code of my program must interfere with the rename process.

Are there any alternatives to "renameTo"?

Comment: Start by reading through the [JavaDocs for `File#renameTo`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/io/File.html#renameTo(java.io.File)). Remember, the directory you are "moving" the file to should already exist

Comment: @MadProgrammer the file already exists and the directory is correct. I can read the data from the txt file using the while loop however I cannot rename the file itself.

Comment: Close the scanner before the rename.

Comment: And please don't call a variable that contains a filename `directory`.

Comment: Yes, there most definitely is an alternative:  [Files.move](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#move%28java.nio.file.Path,java.nio.file.Path,java.nio.file.CopyOption...%29).  It’s superior to the java.io.File class because it will always either succeed or throw an informative exception.

Comment: However if this doesn't work neither will anything else. The underlying operation is the same.

Comment: Yeah, I forgot about closing the scanner, thanks @user207421